# Is there a way to fetch wallet public keys for n number of associated token addresses on Solana?

Tags: reactjs, solana, solana-web3js

Solana's SPL library has `getAssociatedTokenAddress` for fetching an associated token account given a wallet pubkey. Is there a method to go the other way?

I have a list of associated token addresses and I'd like to fetch the owner's pubkey.

There's a `getAccount` rpc call that returns a single `Account` with owner as one of the properties. However, is there a way to fetch multiple accounts or better yet, just filter the response to be just the `owner` property?

Answer (score 1):

Since `getAssociatedTokenAddress` hashes together the wallet, mint, and program pubkeys, it's impossible to reverse the derivation.

When you use `getAccount`, be sure to use `jsonParsed` encoding, since the top-level "owner" reported is actually the owning *program*, and not the owning *wallet*.

If you want to get multiple accounts, you can use `getMultipleAccounts` https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getmultipleaccounts and then get the owner for each account.

And there is no way to filter the returned response to a subset of the data in the account.